# how to drop shadows under sprites in Top-down view with cocos2d

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I just started learning OpenGL and cocos2d and I need an advice.
I'm writing a game in which player is allowed to touch and move rectangles on the screen in a top-down view. Every time a rectangle is touched, it moves up (towards the screen) in z direction and is scaled a bit to look like it's closer than the rest. It drops down to z = 0 after touch ends.

I'd like the risen rectangles to drop shadow under them, but can't get it to work. What approach would you recommend for the best result?

Here's what I have so far.
During setup I turn on the depth buffer and then:
1. all the textures are generated with CCRenderTexture
2. the generated textures are used as an atlas to create CCSpriteBatchNode
3. when a rectangle (tile) is touched:

```
static const float _raisedScale = 1.2;
static const float _raisedVertexZ = 30;

...

-(void)makeRaised
{
    _state = TileStateRaised;
    self.scale = _raisedScale;
    self.scale = _raisedScale;
    self.vertexZ = _raisedVertexZ;
    _glowOverlay.vertexZ = _raisedVertexZ;
    _glowOverlay.opacity = 255;

}
```

glow overlay is used to "light up" the rectangle. 
After that I animate it using `-(void)update:(ccTime)delta`

Is there a way to make OpenGl cast the shadow for me using cocos? For example using shaders or OpenGL shadowing. Or do I have to use a texture overlay to simulate the shadow?

What do you recommend? How would you do it?

Sorry for a newbie question, but it's all really new to me and I really need your help
.

EDIT 6th of March

I managed to get sprites with shadow overlay show under the tiles and it looks ok until one tile has to drop shadow on another which has a non-zero vertexZ value. I tried to create additional shadow sprites which would be scaled and shown on top of the other tiles (usually rising or falling down), but I have problems with animation (tile up, tile down).

Answer (score 3):

Why complicate the problem.

Simply create a projections of how the shadow would look like using your favourite graphics editing program and save it as a png. When the object is lifted, insert your shadowSprite behind your lifted object (you can shift it left/right depending on where you think your light source is).

When the user drops the object down, the show can remain under the object and move with it, making it self visible when the item is lifted again.

Comment: Eyeah, that's how I've done it. The problem, and I'm sorry - I should've mentioned it in my question, is that it is possible that player can mov many tiles at once, so it's possible that one tile is going to be casting shadow at a then-rising-up tile. I'll edit the question